# Logging stderr and stdout to log file and handling errors in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, stderr

**RESOLUTION:**

See [Send stderr/stdout messages to function and trap exit signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876345/send-stderr-stdout-messages-to-function-and-trap-exit-signal)

**Edit**
I see that I have not been precise enough in my original post, sorry about that! So now I will incldue code example of my bash script with refined questions:

My four questions:

1. How can I send **stdout** to *file* and **stderr** to *log()* function in mysql command in STEP 2
2. How can I send **stdout** and **stderr** to *log()* function in gzip STEP 2 and rsync command STEP 3?
3. How to read **stdout** and **stderr** in log() function in question 1 and 2 above?
4. How can I still trap all errors in the *onexit()* function?

**In generel**: I want stdout and stderr to go to log() function so the messages can be put to specific log file according to specific format, but in some cases, like for mysqldump command, stdout need to go to file. Also, error occurs and is sent to stderr, I want to end up in onexit() function after the log statement is finished.

```bash
#!/bin/bash -Eu
# -E: ERR trap is inherited by shell functions.
# -u: Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.

# Example script for handling bash errors.  Exit on error.  Trap exit.
# This script is supposed to run in a subshell.
# See also: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling

#  Trap non-normal exit signals: 2/INT, 3/QUIT, 15/TERM,
trap onexit 1 2 3 15 ERR

# ****** VARIABLES STARTS HERE ***********
BACKUP_ROOT_DIR=/var/app/backup
BACKUP_DIR_DATE=${BACKUP_ROOT_DIR}/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
EMAIL_FROM="foo@bar.com"
EMAIL_RECIPIENTS="bar@foo.com"
...
# ****** VARIABLES STARTS HERE ***********

# ****** FUNCTIONS STARTS HERE ***********
# Function that checks if all folders exists and create new ones as required
function checkFolders()
{
    if [ ! -d "${BACKUP_ROOT_DIR}" ] ; then
        log "ERROR" "Backup directory doesn't exist"
        exit
    else
        log "INFO" "All folders exists"
    fi

    if [ ! -d "${BACKUP_DIR_DATE}" ] ; then
        mkdir ${BACKUP_DIR_DATE} -v
        log "INFO" "Created new backup directory"
    else
        log "WARN" "Backup directory already exists"
    fi
}

# Function executed when exiting the script, either because of an error or successfully run
function onexit() {
    local exit_status=${1:-$?}

    # Send email notification with the status
    echo "Backup finished at `date` with status ${exit_status_text} | mail -s "${exit_status_text} - backup" -S from="${EMAIL_FROM}" ${EMAIL_RECIPIENTS}"
    log "INFO" "Email notification sent with execution status ${exit_status_text}"
   
    # Print script duration to the console
    ELAPSED_TIME=$((${SECONDS} - ${START_TIME}))
    log "INFO" "Backup finished" "startDate=\"${START_DATE}\", endDate=\"`date`\", duration=\"$((${ELAPSED_TIME}/60)) min $((${ELAPSED_TIME}%60)) sec\""
    
    exit ${exit_status}
}

# Logs to custom log file according to preferred log format for Splunk
# Input:
#   1. severity (INFO,WARN,DEBUG,ERROR)
#   2. the message
#   3. additional fields
#
function log() {
    local print_msg="`date +"%FT%T.%N%Z"` severity=\"${1}\",message=\"${2}\",transactionID=\"${TRANS_ID}\",source=\"${SCRIPT_NAME}\",environment=\"${ENV}\",application=\"${APP}\""

    # check if additional fields set in the 3. parameter
    if [ $# -eq 3 ] ; then
        print_msg="${print_msg}, ${3}"
    fi

    echo ${print_msg} >> ${LOG_FILE}
}
# ****** FUNCTIONS ENDS HERE ***********

# ****** SCRIPT STARTS HERE ***********
log "INFO" "Backup of ${APP} in ${ENV} starting"

# STEP 1 - validate
log "INFO" "1/3 Checking folder paths"
checkFolders

# STEP 2 - mysql dump
log "INFO" "2/3 Dumping ${APP} database"
mysqldump --single-transaction ${DB_NAME} > ${BACKUP_DIR_DATE}/${SQL_BACKUP_FILE}
gzip -f ${BACKUP_DIR_DATE}/${SQL_BACKUP_FILE}
log "INFO" "Mysql dump finished."

# STEP 3 - transfer
# Files are only transferred if all commands has been running successfully. Transfer is done with use of rsync
log "INFO" "3/3 Transferring backup file"
rsync -r -av ${BACKUP_ROOT_DIR}/ ${BACKUP_TRANSFER_USER}@${BACKUP_TRANSFER_DEST}

# ****** SCRIPT ENDS HERE ***********
onexit
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that your log function looks like this (it just `echo`s the first argument):

```
log() { echo "$1"; }
```

To save the stdout of mysqldump to some file and call your log() function for every line in stderr, do this:

```
mysqldump 2>&1 >/your/sql_dump_file.dat | while IFS= read -r line; do log "$line"; done
```

If you wanted to use xargs, you could do it this way. However, you'd be starting a new shell every time.

```
export -f log
mysqldump 2>&1 >/your/sql_dump_file.dat | xargs -L1 bash -i -c 'log $@' _
```

Comment: stdout from mysqldump need to be written to dump.sql file, so I can´t redirect stderr to stdout. Let me quess, the first statement stores stderr to log.sh file?

Comment: This: `mysqldump 2>&1 | ./log.sh` pipes both the stderr and stdout outputs from mysqldump to a Bash script called log.sh.

Comment: ok, sorry. Now I see it. But is it really required to create to shell scripts for this?

Comment: What exactly is your log() function? You didn't specify.

Comment: logFunction takes one parameter and prints out to an log file according to specific format.

Comment: Is it your own function? Is it a utility? What language is it written in?

Comment: my own, written in bash

Comment: So what you actually want is to save the stdout of mysqldump to some file and call your log() function for every line in stderr?

Comment: Promising, but you need to double-quote `$line` to ensure that it's passed as a _single_ argument to `log`; similarly, you need to use `xargs -I {} log {}` to ensure that each input line is passed as a _as a single argument_ to `log`. However, given that the OP says `log` is a _function_, this _won't work at all_.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks - forgot those double quotes. Wasn't aware that xargs doesn't work with functions, but it makes sense. I guess you'd need to export the function first and start it in a new shell (which might be too heavy). Alternatively, you could use a while loop.

Comment: Alright, this should work. :)

Comment: :) +; quibble: use `IFS= read -r line` to read input lines _unmodified_ (otherwise, leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mylogger() { printf "Log: %s\n" "$(</dev/stdin)"; }

mysqldump ... 2>&1 >dumpfilename.sql | mylogger
```

Answer (score 2):

Both [Cyrus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735534/45375) and [Oleg Vaskevich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735485/45375) offer viable solutions for redirecting stderr to a shell function.

What they both imply is that **it makes sense for your function to accept *stdin* input rather than expecting input *as an argument*.**

To explain the idiom they use:

```
mysqldump ... 2>&1 > sdtout-file | log-func-that-receives-stderr-via-stdin
```

- `2>&1` ... redirects stderr to the *original* stdout

  - from that point on, any stderr input is redirected to stdout
- `> sdtout-file` *then* redirects the original stdout stdout to file `stdout-out-file`

  - from that point on, any stdout input is redirected to the file.

Since `> stdout-file` comes *after* `2>&1`, the net result is:

- stdout output is redirected to file `stdout-file`
- stderr output is sent to [the original] stdout

Thus, `log-func-that-receives-stderr-via-stdin` only receives the previous command's *stderr* input through the pipe, via *its* *stdin*.

Similarly, **your original approach - `command 2> >(logFunction)` - works in *principle*, but requires that your `log()` function read from *stdin* rather than expect *arguments***:

The following illustrates the principle:

```
ls / nosuchfile 2> >(sed s'/^/Log: /') > stdout-file
```

- `ls / nosuchfile` produces *both* stdout and stderr output.
- stdout output is redirected to file `stdout-file`.
- `2> >(...)` uses an [output] [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to redirect stderr output to the command enclosed in `>(...)` - **that command receives input via *its stdin***.

  - `sed s'/^/Log: /'` reads from its stdin and prepends string `Log:` to each input line.

Thus, your `log()` function should be rewritten to process *stdin*:

- *either*: by implicitly passing the input to another stdin-processing utility such as `sed` or `awk` (as above).
- *or*: by using a `while read ...` loop to process each input line in a shell loop:

```sh
log() {
  # `read` reads from stdin by default
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf 'STDERR line: %s\n' "$line"
  done
}

mysqldump ... 2> >(log) > stdout-file
```